# What's the meaning of a number after a backslash in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

```
(a|b)\1
```

What does `\1` mean in this expression?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`\1` - it means the first capturing group in the matched expression. `\n` would be the nth capturing group. (Note that `\0` would be whole match). In many engines, the upperlimit for n is 9, but some support up to 99 as well.

When used in regex like `(a|b)\1`, it means that after a or b, the next character should be the first captured group, which is a or b so the regex here would match `aa` or `bb`.

Comment: \2 it means the second group in the match expression? right? \3...\9 means the third...nineth group in the match expression?

Comment: @bitmapdata.com - Yes. If there is one.

Comment: @bitmapdata.com - You too. You can accept as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker - BF moment. Corrected.

Comment: This feature is called backreference; A backreference in a regular expression identifies a previously matched group and looks for exactly the same text again.

Answer (score 30):

It refers to what was matched in the first set of parentheses, the first group. Subsequent number means subsequent parentheses.

```
(1|2)(3|4)\1\2
```

Would match:

```
1313
1414
2323
2424
```

Note that if you have nested groups, just count from the opening brace (left brace).

```
(groupOne(groupTwo)stillOne(groupThree(groupFour)))
```

Comment: Thanks!^^ you too great answer! merry christmas^^

Comment: Thanks @bitmapdata.com ! Merry christmas and a happy and wonderful 2012!